# ¿Por qué javac no se reconoce como comando interno o externo?

Tags: java, windows

Estoy intentando compilar usando **javac** en la consola de Windows (cmd), pero si escribo `javac` me dice:

> "javac" no se reconoce como comando externo o interno

*Me ocurrió lo mismo con pip en python y nunca lo solucioné.*

Agregue el path de diferentes formas pero ninguna funciona. Luego, intenté compilar de forma manual y si funciono, es decir:

```
C:\directorio\del\archivo\a\compilar>nombre del archivo C:\directorio\del\javac
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primero que nada, te recomiendo crear la variable JAVA_HOME en tu entorno de trabajo. Para esto, ve a Propiedades del Sistema, Variables de Entorno y registra la siguiente variable:

```
Nombre: JAVA_HOME
Valor: <ubicación de la instalación de JDK>
```

Ejemplo del valor: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131 (hazlo sin el `\` al final)

Luego, debes editar la variable PATH del sistema (con mucho cuidado) y agregarle lo siguiente **al inicio**:

```
Nombre: PATH
Valor: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;<resto del valor de PATH>
```

Acepta los cambios realizados, cierra todas tus líneas de comando (CMD) que tengas abierto. Ahora, abre uno nuevo e ingresa `javac -version`. La salida debería corresponder a la versión que tienes del JDK

Ejemplo (en mi cmd de Windows)

```
C:\Users\Luiggi>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_131
```

Para `pip` es similar. Debes editar la variable PATH y, al inicio, agregar la ruta de la carpeta donde se encuentra `pip`. Aceptar, cerrar todos los terminales, volver a abrir cmd y ejecutar `pip`.

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema. Ya hice lo de las variables de entorno y las guardo, pero cuando vuelvo a ingresar ya no estan. El SO que uso es Win 10. cuando actualizo el path por cmd, puedo ejecutar normalmente el javac, pero reinicio cmd y ya no funciona. en las variables de entorno veo una de oracle, donde apunta a una carpeta donde esta el java.exe, el javaw.exe y el javaws.exe, los tipos de archivos son symlink. Trate de crear un symlink pero cuando lo copio a la carpeta, se cambia el path y queda sirviento para tres cosas...Estoy con la cuenta de administrador. No se que hacer, no se si se

Comment: @luis yo publicaría una nueva pregunta sobre eso. Básicamente, tu problema es que para editar PATH no es bueno hacerlo desde CMD sino desde System Environment Variables o Variables de Entorno de Sistema.

Comment: Una puntualización, porque acabo de agregar la ruta para usar **javac** en mi classpath de usuario y no ha funcionado: **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin** Problemas con los espacios, si se añade entre comillas, ya funciona: **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin"**

Answer (score 0):

Después de instalar el JDK, puedes compilar clases Java indicandole al sistema la ruta absoluta hasta **javac**, como tu dices, de forma manual, ya que el sistema no tiene registrada la ruta de acceso para este comando:

```
C:\directorio\del\archivo\a\compilar>nombre del archivo C:\directorio\del\javac
```

Esta instrucción le permite al sistema encontrar tanto el fichero a compilar como el comando a utilizar y puede acortarse si abrimos la terminal (cmd) en el directorio donde está el fichero a compilar.

No puedes utilizar el comando **javac**, a secas, porque es necesario indicarle al sistema donde encontrarlo (cosa que haces con la instrucción anterior). Debemos añadir la ruta en las **Variables de entorno**, generalmente en las de nuestro usuario. Para hacerlo y de forma general vamos a:

> Panel de Control / Sistema / Configuración avanzada de sistema

Con esto se abre la ventana *Propiedades del sistema*, pulsar el botón "Variables de entorno..." abrirá una nueva ventana como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la parte de arriba tienes las variables para el usuario actual. Lo normal será añadir tu ruta en la variable ***PATH***, si no existe la creamos (Nueva...), de otra forma añadimos la ruta a **javac** a la lista de paths ya existentes, bien con un doble clic sobre la fila de PATH o bien seleccionándola y pulsando "Editar...". Esto abre una nueva ventana para añadir / modificar los valores de la variable.

> **Importante:** los paths o rutas, se separan por punto y coma, sin poner uno al
>   final de la última ruta, y si contienen espacios hay que usar comillas
>   para asegurarnos de que funcionan.

Ejemplo:

```
C:\xampp\php;C:\xxx\miprogrma\libs;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin"
```

Añadida la ruta deseada, pulsamos "Aceptar" en las tres ventanas emergentes que tenemos abiertas y cerramos la ventana de *Opciones del sistema* que abrimos desde el *Panel de control*.

Para comprobar que que el comando **javac** se encuentra disponible y funciona correctamente, abrir una consola (si la teníamos abierta cerrarla para que pueda reconocer la nueva configuración) y escribir:

```
javac -version
```

Si hicimos todo bien, nos devolverá un mensaje indicando la versión instalada:

```
javac 1.8.0_112
```