# ejecutar una clase Java desde el cmd da error no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal

Tags: java, windows, windows10

He creado una classe que necesito ejecutar desde el cmd de Windows, pero no hay manera de que se me ejecute. He actualizado java, he probado mil comandos diferentes, pero da igual lo que haga que el error es siempre el mismo:

> Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal "nombre de la classe"

Básicamente lo que tengo que hacer es poner java nombreclase parametro(en el caso de mi codigo el nombre de un fichero). Por si sirve de ayuda pongo el inicio del código a continuación:

```js
package dam_m06b0_eac1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 *
 * @author theda
 */
public class VeureInfo {

public static File nomDirectoriFitxer = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
```

La ruta completa donde se encuentra la clase es la siguiente:

> C:\Users\theda\OneDrive\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\DAM_M06B0_EAC1\src\dam_m06b0_eac1\VeureInfo.java

Pongo una imagen de diversos comandos que he ido probando (de tantos otros). He probado tanto con -classpath como sin el:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado incluso de intentar ejecutar otra clase distinta y salta el mismo error, así que supongo que estoy haciendo algo mal a la hora de usar el comando.

Comment: Imagino que te habrás asegurado de que Java está instalado correctamente. Los errores que da al intentar usar `javac` parecen indicar que tienes  algún problema de configuración en cuanto a las rutas, hay una variable que le indica a Java dónde buscar los archivos y parece que en tu caso no está bien configurada [ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/87365/29967). En cuanto a ejecutar la clase, [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3670/29967) indica con claridad la forma de hacerlo y por qué.

Comment: puedes poner java -version y mostrarnos que sale

Comment: Parece que instalaste solo el JRE, te hizo falta el JDK agrega la ruta de javac correctamente, el que se ejecuta con el comando java es el .class no el .java

Comment: El JDK lo puedes descargar desde aquí: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnes

El tuyo sería "jdk-8u144-windows-x64.exe" (si ejecutas un Windows de 64 bit, lo cual hoy en día es muy probable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure la variable path c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

Ejemplo de como configurar la variable de entorno: https://www.java.com/es/download/help/path.xml

Una vez configurado ejecutas desde el cmd java - jar c:\ruta

Comment: muchas gracias, solucionado!

Comment: Nestor, intenta mejorar la explicacion. No des las instrucciones solo si no explica como configurarlo. Al autor le ha servido pero puede que futuros users tengan dudas. Mira [answer] para mejorarla. Un saludo

Comment: ejemplo de como configurar la variable de entorno (https://www.java.com/es/download/help/path.xml)

Answer (score 1):

No encuentra el `javac` en el path del sistema. Lo puedes lanzar colocando la ruta directa en cmd.

```
c:\java\javac.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes de instalar el jdk en tu ordenador una vez hecho entrar en la carpeta dende se instalo, por defecto en Archivos de Programa ir hasta la carpeta bin "/java/jdk 1.8.../bin" y copiar esa ruta en las variables de entorno del sistema la cual encontraras en sistema, configuracion avanzada del sistema, variables de entorno

Comment: una vez hecho eso abre el cmd y escribe "javac" y pulsa intro , si sale informacion relativa a la version de java, lo habras instalado correctamente si no no saldra nada xD

Comment: puedes editar la respuesta y añadir lo que creas necesario en lugar de poner comentarios, queda todo más claro